# Convert encoding from CP1252 to UTF-8

Tags: php, yii

My mysql db is used by 2 web sites: the first is built in yii, second just a usual php made site. So I have a usual registration in the second site, after submission a form results in db are non-readable (in Russian), but after output of user profile the results are back to normal russian. But my yii web site displays results exactly like in db (non readable). I tried to encode it via `utf8_encode` and result was also unreadable. So please tell me how to avoid this coding issue in yii?

Comment: Is your DB in utf8 or CP1252? I have this at the top in my Yii `config file: header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In DB declare the encoding (utf8 or 1252):

```
'db'=>array(
      'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=smartworkspace',
      'emulatePrepare' => true,
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => '010101',
      'charset' => 'utf8',
      'tablePrefix' => 'sw_'
    ),
```

And put a header to let the browser know what encoding you are using to show the page:

```
header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

I have it in my config file so it affects all the rest.

Comment: I understand that you are right, and I have the same things in my config. But still non-readable symbols. I will seek problem in my script for submition, maybe something wrong at the very beginning. Thanks!